# Can you give a potion to a beast or monster?

Tags: dnd-5e, healing, potions

I'm curious about the rules regarding the administration of potions to beasts, monsters and ect.

Spells, such as healing word, work the same way they would on any humanoid/ player, so do potions work in the same way?

For example, say my mount was down h.p, could I realistically feed a potion to it and the effects hold?

Comment: heh, this question reminds me the first box of this oots episode http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0375.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes

Unless the potion explicitly says that that it requires humanoids, then it doesn't.

Here is the text for [Potion of Healing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/potion-of-healing):

> You regain hit points when you drink this potion. The number of hit points depends on the potion’s rarity, as shown in the Potions of Healing table. Whatever its potency, the potion’s red liquid glimmers when agitated.

As you can see, there is no requirement for the target to be a humanoid or player character.

Just keep in mind that they have to be willing to drink it. There are no rules to allow you to force feed anyone a potion.

Comment: The following links explain some of your other points: "[Can one force-feed an opponent a potion in combat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77800)" and " [Can an unconscious person drink a potion?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84186)", also the following closed question: "[Administering a potion to a conscious enemy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/121886)"